# How can I make an OAuth request from my external application to any JIRA instance and make REST API calls?

Tags: oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

I have an external application(consumer of the API) that needs to make an authenticated request to *any* JIRA instance using OAuth and make REST API calls to obtain information from that instance. Setting up an application link allows me to create a link *from* my JIRA instance *to* an external application. I am trying to achieve the opposite. Is it possible to use Jira's REST API similar to that of Facebook or Twitter by creating a developer account and registering the consumer application to receive the consumer ID and secret? 
My question is similar to [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12286957/oauth-authentication-from-an-add-on-to-jira-rest-api).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the JIRA authentication documentation is not the best. I believe JIRA only supports OAuth1, so the authentication process will be slightly different from the other providers you mentioned.

Comment: According to the JIRA documentation, I have to start the OAuth process by creating an application link. For any value of the application url, it says "No response was received from the URL, it may be invalid". From what I understand, the first step to create an application link is used to link JIRA to an external app and I am asked to enter a consumer key and secret instead of receiving them. How do I achieve the opposite using OAuth1?